# Jquery .animate() и бесплатный хостинг

Tags: jquery, slider, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Такой вопрос: сделал сайтик со слайдером, на локалке слайдер работает идеально на всех браузерах отлично, в ИЕ 8 на локалке тоже отлично, но я его выложил на бесплатный хостинг, и теперь в ИЕ 8 слайдер лагает (то есть рывками двигается), а в остальных браузерах нормально.

Может ли это быть связано с бесплатным хостингом или же всё-таки 
это я напортачил с кодом?

Comment: На бесплатных хостингах зачастую есть реклама, возможно, она как-то влияет.

Comment: На этом хостинге нет рекламы.

Answer (score 1):

Это проблема с ИЕ8, не с кодом. Возможно данный браузер не поддерживает анимации.